# Checking for a word inside a string

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a way of detecting wheter or not a certain word is present in a string.
For example, if I have the string "hi, this is me" I want to make sure "hi" is present;
What I tried so far:

```
bool containsWord () {
    string str = "hi, this is me";
    return str.Contains ("hi");
}
```

Does not work properly: the problem with this is that I need to make sure the word itself is present and is not part of another word.
With the code as it is, doing:

```
bool containsWord () {
    string str = "this is me";
    return str.Contains ("hi");
}
```

would still return true since "hi" is still a substring of "t**hi**s".
How can I avoid that?

Comment: [`Regex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 // Add other punctuation if need 
var array = str.Split(" ,;.".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) ;
bool containsWord = array.Any(s => s.Equals("hi", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 2):

use some regular expressions - `Regex.IsMatch(@"\bhi\b");`
don't forget to add `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`